How to prove that this fundamental property of Markov chains implies conditioned independence of future and past
I am currently studying Markov chains on the book "Probability-$1$" by Albert N. Shiryaev.
After defining a probability model $(\Omega, P(\Omega), \mathbb{P}) $, the author checks the validity of the following fundamental property of conditional probabilities: $$\mathbb{P}\{\xi_{k+1} = a_{k+1} | \xi_k = a_k, \dots, \xi_0 = a_0 \} = \mathbb{P}\{\xi_{k+1} = a_{k+1} | \xi_k = a_k \}$$
Later he writes:

Now, if we use the evident equation
$$\mathbb{P}((A \cap{B}) |C) = \mathbb{P}(A | (B \cap{C})) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B|C) $$
we find from [the first equation] that $$\mathbb{P}\{\xi_n = a_n,\dots, \xi_{k+1} = a_{k+1} | \xi_0, \dots, \xi_k \} = \mathbb{P}\{\xi_n = a_n,\dots,\xi_{k+1} = a_{k+1} | \xi_k \}$$

I couldn't make use of the "hint" to get this result. In other words, I can't figure out how to choose A, B, C properly to find the desired property of independence of future and past. I tried many "combinations" but they just don't seem to work.
If necessary, I can add some of my attempts. At the moment, I think they would only make the question longer as they didn't help me at all. Thanks in advance.

The proof is by induction on the number of future events. The first equation establishes the assertion for one future event (namely, the future event $\{\xi_{k+1}=a_{k+1}\}$). Here's  the assertion for two future events:
$$P(\xi_{k+2}=a_{k+2},\xi_{k+1}=a_{k+1} \mid \xi_k=a_k,\ldots,\xi_0=a_0)
=P(\xi_{k+2}=a_{k+2},\xi_{k+1}=a_{k+1} \mid \xi_k=a_k).
$$ To save effort, and to add clarity, I'm going to abuse notation so that $k$ stands for the event $\{\xi_k=a_k\}$. Then the assertion is:
$$P(k+2,k+1\mid k, \ldots,0)=P(k+2,k+1\mid k).$$ The proof of this assertion proceeds as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(k+2,k+1\mid k,\ldots,0)&\stackrel{(1)}=P(k+2\mid k+1,k,\ldots,0)P(k+1\mid k,\ldots,0)\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=P(k+2\mid k+1)P(k+1\mid k)\\
&\stackrel{(3)}=P(k+2\mid k+1, k)P(k+1\mid k)\\
&\stackrel{(4)}=P(k+2, k+1\mid k)
\end{aligned}
$$ Steps (1) and (4) are the hint [the "evident equation"], while step (2) is the fundamental property [the first equation].
The tricky step is (3). This can be shown by considering all possible  sequences $A:=\{\xi_{k-1}=a_{k-1},\ldots, \xi_0=a_0\}$ of past events:
$$\begin{aligned}P(k+2, k+1, k)&=
\sum_A P(k+2,k+1,k,A)\\&
\stackrel{(5)}=\sum_A P(k+2\mid k+1)P(k+1,k,A)\\
&=P(k+2\mid k+1)P(k+1, k)
\end{aligned}
$$ Rearrange this to get $P(k+2\mid k+1,k)=P(k+2\mid k+1)$. Step (5) is again the fundamental property.

Thanks for your help. I wonder if you could explain step $(3)$ more

@DavideMasi I've added more detail to step (3).

Delightful answer, thank you very much!
